# For OS X Safari what icons sizes and HTML link tags should I use to display a logo in the address bar?

Tags: html, macos, safari, icons

I'm building out my site and want to set icons for favorites and address bars and bookmarks. I found all the information for every browser but OS XX Safari. Does anybody know the Safari standards? Here is what I have for all else: